# c++ class strange behavior

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
struct Test {
    int parameter(int) { return 0; }
    int nonparameter() { return 0; }
    void package() {
        std::function<int()> pp = std::bind(&Test::nonparameter, this);
        // std::function<int(int)> np = std::bind(&Test::parameter, this);
    }
};
```

I was doing some function classification jobs in visual stuido, when I need to do something like the upper code saying, something strange behavior confused me so much that the comment line can not be compiled, am I missing some important concept. Any answer will be appreciated.
environment : visual studio professional 2022

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/placeholders

Comment: Simplest answer is don't use `std::bind` use lambda functions. `std::function<int(int)> np = [this](int i) { return parameter(i); }`

Comment: looking up for my previous notes, the code `std::function<int(int)> np = std::bind(&Test::parameter, this, std::placeholders::_1);` like this can be compiled.